# How to run discordpy terminal in bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-os

i was looking to make a command for my bot that would allow me to run commands directly through the bot
suchas:

input: /run await ctx.send("hi stackoverflow")

bot: hi stackoverflow

I have been researching how to make such a command in discordpy, but the closest i got was using exec, but it just threw up `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: SyntaxError: 'await' outside function (<string>, line 1)`

I hate to ask without proper code samples but any help is appreciated
<3

Comment: Have you tried using `exec()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a command line interface, I would suggest something like this:

```
import threading, time


def waitfor():
    cmd = input('command: ')
    print(cmd)
    ## do command processing here eg. eval(cmd)

def runthread():
    t = threading.Thread(target=waitfor)
    t.start()
    return t

async def commandInterface():
    t = runthread()
    while 1:
        if not t.is_alive():
            t = runthread()
        time.sleep(1)
        ## loop stuff

client.loop.create_task(commandInterface)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

This uses the threading module to wait for an input and the run the command, without blocking the rest of the program. Obviously it would need to be adapted to fit your needs but this could be a good start.